# How to include labels in sns heatmap

Tags: python, visualization, numpy, seaborn

I got this matrix

```
    120     100     80      40      20      10      5       0
120 64.21   58.20   51.20   56.37   47.00   45.61   46.86   2.16
100 62.84   57.80   50.60   51.32   39.43   39.30   42.80   0.89
80  62.62   56.20   51.20   51.61   46.23   37.20   42.20   5.32
40  62.05   52.10   44.20   48.79   42.22   35.16   41.80   1.81
20  61.65   50.90   42.30   46.23   44.83   32.70   41.50   6.24
10  59.69   50.20   40.10   40.20   44.28   32.80   39.90   12.31
5   59.05   49.20   40.60   38.90   44.10   30.80   32.80   9.91
0   56.20   49.10   40.50   38.60   36.20   32.20   31.50   0.00
```

I know how to plot heatmap for the values inside by specifying it as numpy array and then using

```
ax = sns.heatmap(nd, annot=True, fmt='g')
```

But can someone help me how do I include the column and row labels? The column labels and row labels are given (120,100,80,42,etc.)

Comment: Also the generated matrix if I am not wrong(will confirm) plots the matrix as it is via colours densities, so we know what is what(look at annotations, xticklabels, yticklabels etc..).... Docs might help...https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Comment: Thank you man, I didn't notice the tiny detail for list in it.

Answer (score 23):

I got your problem like this way:
You want to show labels on the x and y-axis on the seaborn heatmap. So for that, `sns.heatmap()` function has two parameters which are `xticklabels` for x-axis and `yticklabels` for y-axis labels.

Follow the code snippet below:

```
import seaborn as sns # for data visualization
flight = sns.load_dataset('flights') # load flights datset from GitHub seaborn repository

# reshape flights dataset in proper format to create seaborn heatmap
flights_df = flight.pivot('month', 'year', 'passengers') 

sns.heatmap(flights_df)# create seaborn heatmap
```

**Output >>>**
[image]

Now, we are changing x and y-axis labels using  `xticklabels` and `yticklabels` sns.heatmap() parameters.

```
x_axis_labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] # labels for x-axis
y_axis_labels = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,101,111,121] # labels for y-axis

# create seabvorn heatmap with required labels
sns.heatmap(flights_df, xticklabels=x_axis_labels, yticklabels=y_axis_labels)
```

**Output >>>**
[image]

For an in-depth explanation follow the [seaborn heatmap](https://indianaiproduction.com/seaborn-heatmap/) tutorial.

Comment: Can we have different colours for labels of the heatmap?

Answer (score 8):

Here's how we can add simple X-Y labels in sns heatmap:

```
s = sns.heatmap(cm_train, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues')
s.set(xlabel='X-Axis', ylabel='Y-Axis')
```

OR

```
s.set_xlabel('X-Axis', fontsize=10)
s.set_ylabel('Y-Axis', fontsize=10)
```